# Accessing collectionView property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have the collection view and need to reloadData. My collectionView is in the following class

CustomViewController.h

```
@interface CustomViewController : UIViewController <MosaicLayoutDelegate>{
    __weak IBOutlet UICollectionView *_collectionView;
}
```

But I need to know how could I access collectionView property in the different class to achieve the following line code? The following X is my question.

```
[X reloadData];
```